# Preserve encoding after SAX parsing

Tags: java, xml, encoding, sax, cdata

I have an XML document that contains attributes like the following:

```
<Tag Body="&lt;p&gt;">
```

I want to preserve the text in the Body attribute exactly as-is; however, the parsing method is converting the text to "<p>". I want to keep the "&", "l", "t", ";", etc.

I'm using the Java SAX API to parse the XML document like so:

```
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
    xmlReader.setContentHandler(new MyHandler());
    xmlReader.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler(System.err));
    xmlReader.parse(convertToFileURL(myFileName));
```

The relevant code in `MyHandler.java` is:

```
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts)
throws SAXException
{
    if (qName.equals("Tag")){
        String Body = atts.getValue("Body");
        char []s = Body.toCharArray();  // s[0] will be "<", but I want it to be "&"
    }
}
```

How can I get the parsing method to leave the attribute text alone and not try to convert anything?

Comment: `&lt;p&gt;` in xml equals `<p>` in plain text. If you want output xml-encoded text, just xml encode it, for example, you can use StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Unescaping stuff like &lt; is what parsers are paid to do.

Comment: @user1516873 Thanks for the tip. I've created an answer based on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.

I didn't find a way to stop the parser from unescaping the text to begin with, but I did find a workaround (thatnks @user1516873) to re-escape it afterwards using Apache Commons:

```
String Body = atts.getValue("Body");
String Body_escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(Body);
```

This achieves the desired results.